# Inserting CRLF into a string sequence in Notepad ++

Tags: replace, find, notepad++, newline

I have a text file that has incorrectly placed line breaks. The position where the line break should be placed goes like this **...xxxXxxx...** (every x is a character [a-z] with the capital X being a capital character [a-z]. I want to place the CRLF in front of the capital letter. How do I do it? I can find all these sequences by **Find what: [a-z][A-Z][a-z] (match case 1)** but I don't know what to type in the Replace with field to keep the original text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=\p{lower})(?=\p{upper})`
- Replace with: `\r\n`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\p{lower})  # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a lowercase letter before
(?=\p{upper})   # positive lookahead, make sure we have an uppercase letter after
```

**Replacement:**

```
\r\n            # CRLF
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: @BreadBoxGuy: See my edit, it works with any language.